# OPTIONS Authentication settings in Liferay Not Showing

Tags: liferay-6

I have the follow situation, the authentication option in portal settings of in liferay not show (LDAP, EEM, ....). the page is in blank. any one have an idea? thanks

Comment: Any error log in console?

Comment: Hi! Thanks. no Javascript errors in console log. recently I added the following statement in portal-ex.properties   company.settings.form.authentication=general,ldap,cas,facebook,ntlm,open-id,open-sso,siteminder    ...... still not working

Comment: checking in the logs I found the following errors, 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file 
Only a type can be imported. Resolves to a package com.ca.sfo.util.EEMEncryption 

An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /html/portlet/portal_settings/authentication.jsp 
EEM_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED can not be resolved or is not a field 
68: String = PrefsPropsUtil.getString siteminderUserHeader (company.getCompanyId (), PropsKeys.SITEMINDER_USER_HEADER, PropsValues.SITEMINDER_USER_HEADER);

Comment: Yesm, Check for where com.ca.sfo.util.EEMEncryption is defined.

Comment: is defined in C:\Program Files\CA\Open Space\OSOP\tomcat-7.0.23\webapps\openspace-ext\WEB-INF\ext-impl\classes\com\ca\sfo\util

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was, Reinstall and apply the correct patch.